# how to check data consumption for particular network in Android

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework

i want to calculate data usage from a particular wifi network. i had search about this but didn't get any information . can it possible for us to count or watch how much data from a network has been used in android

Answer (score 1):

I did implemented this kind of functionality, you can do that with the help of **ConnectivityManager**  and **NetworkInfo** classes.

You need to implement **BroadcastReceiver**  for calculate data usage and store WiFi name with usage.
[android developer doc](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html) will help you to do that.

Comment: Actually I did year ago in client PC now i have to start from scratch.